# Implementing a promise within a loop with an api call

Tags: javascript, loops, google-api, promise, google-translate

I'm working with the google translate api.

```
function translate() {
    var languages = [array of languages codes];
    for (var i = 1; i < languages.length; i++) {
        alert("working");
        GoogleTranslate(text, languages[i - 1], languages[i]);
        alert(text);
    }
}

function GoogleTranslate(text, fron, to) {
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    var sourceText = escape(text);
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=APIKEY&source=' + from + '&target=' + to + '&callback=google_translation&q=' + sourceText;
    newScript.src = source;
    alert("sent");

    // send the request off to google by appending 
    $('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
}

// callback
function google_translation(google_response) {
    text.val(google_response.data.translations[0].translatedText);
    alert("translated")
}
```

What i would want to see to know that my code is working the way i want is to have the alerts appear in order: "working", "sent", "translated', "text" and have it repeat.

Instead, I get "working", "sent", "text", "working", "sent", "text"... "translated".. Meaning that the whole google api call did not finish with its callback before the loop ran again.

I have read and heard that I may want to implement a promise, but I'm not sure how to implement this, and if I somehow did, how to get it working within a loop. Can anyone point me to a good website. I want to run a promise with a synchronous function followed by an asynchronous function and then have the loop continue but most of the sites focus on asynchronous calls back to back. Or if possible, a different way of making sure that the whole of the api call is done before the loop continues. Thanks so much for any help!

Edit: heres me calling the api with an ajax

```
function GoogleTranslate (text, from, to, where) {
var g_object = new Object;
g_object.key = "APIKEY";
g_object.source = from;
g_object.target = to;
g_object.q = text;
alert("1");
$.ajax({
  //async: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
  data: g_object,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (response) {
      alert("2");
      where.val(response.data.translations[0].translatedText);  
      alert("3");
  },
  error: function (response) {
    alert('Error:' + response.error.message);
  }
});
}
```

where is the place the translated text should go

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the array of languages is something like

```
['English', 'French', 'German', 'Klingon']
```

And you want to translate from English->French->German->Klingon - the code seems to suggest that's what you are aiming for

Using promises is not too bad a solution

In the code below, there's a reason I'm using `var translate` rather than `function translate` - so the function object is fully self contained

Also, translate MUST be global for the jsonp callback to work - but you probably knew that

```
var translate = function translate(fromtext) {
    var iterate; // this will contain a function to call to jump to the next translation
    var languages = ['English', 'French', 'German', 'Klingon'];

    // this function hasn't changed from your example, except the callback is set to the function within this function
    function GoogleTranslate (text, from, to) {
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        var sourceText = escape(text);
        newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=APIKEY&source=' + from + '&target=' + to + '&callback=translate.google&q=' + sourceText;
        // notice the callback is translate.google, exactly as defined below. ---------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        newScript.src = source;
        console.log("sent");
        // send the request off to google by appending 
        document.head.appendChild(newScript); // use document.head i modern browsers
    }

    // this function hasn't changed, except the call to iterate at the end, and I removed the text.val() call as it made no sense to display the intermediate values of the translation
    translate.google = function (google_response) {
        console.log("translated");
        // when a translation has completed, go do the next one, resolving the promise with the result of this one
        iterate(google_response.data.translations[0].translatedText);
    }

    // slice(1) to work from 1 to end of array
    function reducer(promise, tolanguage, index) {
        //chain the translation to the result of the previous promise
        return promise.then(function(newtext) { // newtext is the result of the previous translation
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // return a new promise
                iterate = resolve; // iterate is called to resolve this promise
                console.log('working');
                // access the previous language through languages array
                // as we have copied the languages from index 1, use the same index in languages to get the from language
                GoogleTranslate(newtext, languages[index], tolanguage);
                console.log(newtext);
            });
        });
    }
    var destinationLanguages = languages.slice(1);
    var result = destinationLanguages.reduce(reducer, Promise.resolve(fromtext)); // prime the loop with the incoming word
    return result;
};
```

Usage

```
translate('hello').then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); //
    // this is where you probably want to do the following
    text.val(result);
});
```

[Array reduce documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

If you could use CORS json with `www.googleapis.com/language/translate`, the code would be far simpler and less hackish

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for your help! I actually have google translate working through a jsonp ajax call if that helps. Ill edit my original question. (im still trying to make sense of your response (:  )

Comment: text.val() updates a textbox with the new translation. This whole function is run when a user clicks a button and the text within the textbox is translated.

Comment: I know it's jsonp. .. i said easier if it was json instead

Comment: I'll add some more comments off that helps

Comment: that would be great! thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: @westcoastbestcoast - I've updated it, separated some of the functions at the bottom to hopefully make it a little more understandable. there was a bug in the original answer in that it wasn't passing the translated word from one translation to the next

Comment: I hate to bother you, but is it possible to simply call the googletranslate function. I have it written down in my js file and dont want to have another function doing the same thing to repeat myelf? and i actually would like to have the result of every translation placed into a new div. Also, it it bad that my console says illegal return on the final return result?

Comment: Id need to see how how you are using it. Or intending to. Code not vague description

Comment: is there a way i can send u it?

Comment: ive tried to explain myself more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082039/getting-a-callback-to-finish-before-continuing-a-loop

Comment: I am so so dumb ... you use jquery ... it handles jsonp and even returns an almost promise to work with!